# Syntax checking with iverilog

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I want to run iverilog just to check syntax in my file. I don't want it to actually compile anything since I'm working on a large codebase and don't want to find and "include" all included files.

```
`include "header.vh"   // not a file in current dir so iverilog can't find it

module test;
input a;
input b;
output c;

assign c = a & b   // missed a semicolon - wanna use iverilog to tell me this

assign d = a + XMR.TO.ANOTHER.MODULE.d;    // Want iverilog to ignore the XMR and move on since there's no syntax issue here

// no endmodule - should also be reported by iverilog
```

Command I tried:

```sh
iverilog -t null -Wall test.v
```

Please help me find a solution... even if you could point me to a different tool, that'd be great.

Comment: what did iverilog tell you? what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `` `include `` to include files that are required for compilation of the code that follows. Verilog does not require modules that are cross-referenced to be compiled first.

Instead, give the compiler a list of files to compile. Then you should be able to use any tool to compile just one of the files and get the syntax errors you are searching for.